# what does "as in" mean, how do I use it correctly?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

the video is talking (https://youtu.be/4kuhQzbc2Tw?t=76)

> "Kind" is a word you've probably heard before.
>   "She is a kind woman.", "He has a kind face."
>   And we mean nice and friendly.
>   Now, you might not be aware that it also is a noun, "as in" category.

I am aware the meaning of what he is saying, namely, "kind" has a meaning of "category".

the speaker uses "as in" there, what does that mean, how do I use it correctly?

Comment: for example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker isn't really using *as in* correctly. He could have said "...it also is a noun, as in 'What kind of car do you drive?'" It means 'as used in this phrase'.

Answer (score 1):

> We can use “as in” when we want to clarify the meaning of something. It’s a way to further the understanding of the reader in a context, and it’s a useful tool to have ready.

[This article](https://grammarhow.com/as-in-meaning/) will explain more about "as in".